# $(document).ready() not firing when calls in head.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, document-ready, head.js

I have an issue using jQuery `$(document).ready` and headjs framework v1.0.3, with the head.ready functionality, only on Internet Explorer (version 11, I can't try on an older version), and only once in ten...

Just before the `</body>` I have :

```
head.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',function() {
    head.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js');
    head.ready(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.class').show();
        });
    });
});
```

And some times, the $(document).ready event is not triggered.
It works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

```
$(window).load doesn't work better.
```

I've try to put the `head.ready()` out but in vain :

```
head.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',function() {
    head.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js');
});
head.ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.class').show();
    });
});
```

I find a solution using `head.ready` instead of `$(document).ready`, but I can't use this solution because the part in the `head.ready(function() {...});` comes from a code shared with platforms not using headjs.

Is anyone ever encountered this problem or have a solution ?

Comment: document.ready has no relationship to loading content dynamically. It only deals with the initial page load.

Comment: what is `head`? `load()` replaces inner html and is not the proper way to load scripts. Also why can't you use script tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there is a race condition. You may wish to check whether the document is already in a ready state in head ready, since `document.ready` won't fire

```
head.ready(function() {
  var readyfunc = function(){
     $('.class').show();
  };

  if (document.readyState === 'complete'){
    readyfunc();
  }else{
    $(document).ready(function() {
      readyfunc();
    });
  }
}
```

See if that works.

Comment: I loaded the page 50 times whithout the problem, so I guess this solution fixes the bug. Thanks !!